# iOS: How to go back to a specific tab or previous tab after closing UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, camera, uitabbarcontroller, overlay

My app runs within a number of tabs, one of which runs a camera with an Overlayview. I have a Close button on the camera and I need some help on how to immediately load the previous tab or a specific tab after closing the camera. Can someone point me in the direction to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Before going to the camera view, you have to save the index of previous tab, and if camera view is cancelled, call `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:prevTabIndex]`, assuming that `prevTabIndex` is previously selected tab's index. Good luck!

**EDIT:**
In your `AppDelegate.h` put property for `previousIndex`, like below:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int previousTabIndex;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

In your `AppDelegate.m` file, do something like this:

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "FirstViewController.h"

#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize previousTabIndex;
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_tabBarController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    self.previousTabIndex = self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;
    return YES;
}

@end
```

In your camera view, you should have some method that will be called, when user taps cancel button, like this:

```
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:appDelegate.previousTabIndex];
}
```

Hope this was helpful. If this does not help you, I really suggest you to read some basics of objective-c and iOS programming. Good Luck!

**EDIT #2**

For storyboards, in the `Tab Bar Controller` scene add `Object` template, set it's class to your `AppDelegate`. Set `UITabbarController`'s `delegate` outlet to the `AppDelegate` object. In your `AppDelegate`, add property like in my first edit, implement

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    self.previousTabIndex = self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;
    return YES;
}
```

And in your camera view, when user cancels the view do

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:appDelegate.previousTabIndex];
```

That's all! Good Luck twice more!

Comment: Where do I save the selectedIndex? Is it in my TabController class, using tabBarController: didSelectViewController: OR tabBar:  didSelectItem: ? Note that I have a view controller inside each tab but exactly do I store it? Or is it better to do it in the AppDelegate?

Comment: You can do that in `UITabbarController`'s delegate method, `didSelectViewController`.

Comment: @ Fahri Azimov, I am very close here is what I have done. I declared an NSUInteger variable to store the selectedIndex in my TabBarController class. Then, I imported the .h file into my CameraView class but when I now write the statement like you suggested above, it tells me that " Use of undefined identifier". Kindly guide me a little bit more. Curiously, I decided to NSlog the point I am saving it but it is not getting called, would you know why? I am on IOS 5.1.

Comment: @Paulo, please, see my comment to @Prince's answer. Use `UITabbarController`'s `- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController` delegate method to store the `previousIndex`.

Comment: It still tells me that "Use of undefined identifier" after I followed your latest comment. Also, it still does not detect the tabs as I change them since I am checking with an NSLog to see if it correctly tracks the tab changes. What else can I do?

Comment: Ok, give me a minute, I'll post full source.

Comment: the tabs in my app use storyboards and are not initialized in the app delegate. I have a TabController Class and the UIImagePickerController class (camera) runs in a different tab. What should I do differently in this scenario in order to be able to close that tab and return to the previous tab? Thanks.

Comment: You had to tell that in first place. See my edited answer, and, you really have to read some iOS programming basics.

Comment: thanks and I was just going to update this post with the correct answer, same as you posted. I was able to figure it out using your first answer. One more thing: if I now want to re-select the tab for the camera and reload it, it shows up as a blank screen. Using PresentViewController: gives me an error "Application tried to present modally an active controller". I basically just always want to re-load the camera when the tab button is pressed. How can I do that or should I open another question for this?

Comment: You have to dismiss your camera view when cancelled, like  `[cameraView dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`. Error you have encountered is enough self-explanatory, and it's saying that you are trying to show the modal view controller that's already visible.

Comment: I always want the tab to load the camera and I have added code in the TabBarController class: In tabBar: didSelectItem: {int barItem = [[tabBar items] indexOfObject:item]; if (barItem == 2) { CameraViewController *camera = [[CameraViewController alloc] init];[self.tabBarController presentViewController:camera animated:YES completion:nil];}}. It doesn't give me an error but it does not show the camera. How can I always show the camera in this tab? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use **tabBarControlller**'s **selectedIndex** property to go back or move to specific tab. Use imagePickerController's didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo to move to specific tab

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    imgview.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = yourPreviousIndex or any index
}
```

**EDIT** Save your previousIndex like this:

```
Add int previousIndex in AppDelegate.h

(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   previousIndex = self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: I added a clarification comment, please check it.

Comment: @Prince, Your edited answer is wrong approach, because, in your code `previousIndex` will be always equal to current `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex`. `previousIndex` should be saved in `- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController` delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

This worked on iOS 9.0

```
UIStoryboard *myStoryBoard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[self.storyboard valueForKey:@"name"] bundle:nil];

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [myStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabStoryboardID"];

tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;

[self presentViewController:tabBarController animated:YES completion:nil];
```